# Ruby DateTime.new confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, locale

I'm still somewhat confused with how to work with **DateTime** in Ruby. I'd like to store GMT in the database, at least I assume I would. But how does one go about creating usable localized DateTimes?

```
date = Date.new(2012, 11, 24)
 => #<Date: 2012-11-24 ((2456256j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> 
new_appt = DateTime.new(date.year, date.month, date.day, 10, 0, 0)
 => #<DateTime: 2012-11-24T10:00:00+00:00 ((2456256j,36000s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

This DateTime object has GMT offset of +00:00. I'd like it to be -07:00 or -08:00 depending on whether the given date is observing daylight savings or not. I could add a last parameter (`+7` or `+8`) but how to calculate?

Is there a way to tell given the date what the time zone offset is (or will be) and factor that into the DateTime.new object so it's can be stored (and retrieved) correctly?

Comment: Are you using Rails, or just Ruby?  Also, where is the "given date" you need to use to calculate the offset coming from?

Comment: Is there any business reason to store in GMT? I'd recommend having all systems speak/store in UTC and do any conversions only when they need to be human readable e.g. in a view.

Comment: @Kevin I agree with the latter half of your comment, but isn't GMT just an older way of saying UTC?

Comment: I'm sorry! I meant UTC. (see...I'm confused!)

Comment: @Nick - This application is Sinatra, actually, and the date in question is local to a region. Always the same region, in this case and will be either PST or PDT...but that will depend on which side of the time change the dates fall on...

Comment: @sawa, pretty much :P Just a lot more helper code available for .utc from what I see, at least in Ruby anyhow.

Comment: @Meltemi, to answer your question, just realised you're using Date and DateTime, if you want to have current time in UTC try `Time.now.utc` and if you want local time use `{variable}.localtime`

Comment: @Kevin, sry, still confused. I'm trying to create a DateTime object for an appointment on some date in the future. so **now** isn't helpful. I'd like to make sure the 10am appointment still occurs at 10am local time if we pass from PDT to PST. But how to create that DateTime object given the date and the hour? Hope that makes sense!?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please refer to the [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-dst-3F) on `Time` for more information.

When creating the variable, you can use `Time.local`, and it will figure out if DST is correct or not.  E.g., to create an appointment at `3.30 pm` you can do: *(my local time is CST)*

```
Time.local 2012, 10, 20, 15, 30
=> 2012-10-20 15:30:00 +0800
```

When storing to the database I would suggest storing as UTC, i.e., `variable.utc` and then if it needs to be rendered again to the user it's just a matter of calling `variable.localtime` once again. From memory, this makes using the time in other languages like JavaScript extremely straightforward.

Comment: thank you! I was looking around the `DateTime` class for my answer and I guess I should have been looking in `Time`!?!